# RequireJs VS Browserify which one is best for JS optimization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, browserify

I am developing single page application with angularJS. For JS optimization currently i have two options one is requireJs and another one is Browserify.

Which one is best for my AngularJs single page application.

Please consider Easy of implementation,Support, Best performance etc

Please suggest

```
.state('root.home',{
        url: '/index.html',
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/header/html/header.html',
                controller: 'headerController'
            },          
            'content-area': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/home/html/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/common/html/footer.html',
                controller: 'footerController'
            }
        },
        data: {
            displayName: 'Home',
         }
    })
```

In my index.html page I am loading needed javascripts and unwanted scripts.Which one is the best approach to load wanted JS file for the home module with AngularJs UI rooter. Please give one example with UI rooter

Answer (score 3):

A couple thoughts:

- Browserify's ease of use wins out. Simply use `require()` and `module.exports`, like you would in any Node module; easier than Require's definition and dependency injection.
- Performance in terms of CPU time for both is negligible. As far as size goes - Require needs to load itself to bootstrap, but Browserify builds standalone bundles. However, Browserify does like to import some Node libraries by default which tends to bump the size up.
- Notably for large apps: requirejs allows fairly transparent asynchronous loading of scripts. Browserify does not. If you have a very large app you want to load incrementally, this may be a factor.
- Notably: Browserify lets you import isomorphic Node.js modules. Since you're using Angular, the app itself won't be isomorphic, but there's a wider body of resources to take advantage of (and they can be brought in with a simple `npm install`)

Comment: I am using angular js UI rooter. For this UI rooter module separation the Browserifyis best method?

Comment: Now my code is in above structure with this AngularJS UI rooter what is best approach(RequireJs/Browserify )

Answer (score -1):

Using AngularJS mean you are not building isomorphic app. My guess would be that you will be sharing less code between client and the node app. If you need only dependency loader in the client then I would say look for requirejs and they are many example available online. Below has good comparison of different available options.

http://www.slant.co/topics/1089/compare/~webpack_vs_browserify_vs_requirejs